# Setting a property in PrepareForSegue is null for ViewDidLoad but correct later on

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties, viewdidload

I have searched up and down on this and found a few that were similar but not my exact problem. In my detail view controller I have a segue that opens a popover table view controller. In the PrepareForSegue method, I set a property of the table view, like so:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"StateSegue"])
    {
        popover = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];
        StatePickerController *statePicker = (StatePickerController *)popover.contentViewController;
        statePicker.delegate = self;
        statePicker.pickerType = @"states";
    }
}
```

I pass both the delegate and the pickerType value. In my table view, StatePickerController, in the header I declared these properties like this:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) id<StatePickerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *pickerType;
```

I know these values are getting passed into my popover controller correctly because later on in didSelectRowAtIndexPath I can reference them both and I get the right delegate and "state", however in the viewDidLoad method, both are still (null).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(150.0, 140.0);
    self.states = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.delegate); //returns (null)
    NSLog(@"%@",self.pickerType); //returns (null)
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%@",self.pickerType); //corectly logs "state"
    NSString *state = [_states objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.delegate stateSelected:state]; //correctly runs method on detailviewcontroller
}
```

Is there some point after the viewDidLoad method where these properties get set? I need access to these values right when the view loads because I need to determine what data populates in the table based on what is passed from the detailviewcontroller.

Comment: Have you tried viewWillAppear instead?

Comment: This is an interesting blog about the life cycle of view controllers in a storyboard: http://vastdevblog.vast.com/blog/2012/04/08/uiviewcontroller-life-cycle/ However, according to that you did everything right. (afaik)

Comment: Aha that does it, @MarkM. So I assume viewWillAppear runs after ViewDidLoad with the properties being set in between at some point. Thanks! I don't know if I have the rep to upvote your response.

Comment: viewWillAppear does run after viewDidLoad. But it will be called again and again if any subsequent viewController is pushed/segued and when this view controller gets visible again. So whatever you do there make sure that the code does not do any harm if it is run again and again.

Comment: Thanks, @HermannKlecker. That is a good link and good to know as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

viewWillAppear is called after viewDidLoad. Use that instead to check the values after the prepareForSegue method.